# Newton interpolation polynomial for finding the value of a logarithmic function

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Function $f(x)=\log x$ is given by 
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FMRq.png).

Using the Newton interpolation polynomial, find $\log 1044$.

It is not specified what type (first or second) of polynomial we need to use.
Could someone show the procedure for this problem?

**EDIT:**

I have the following approximation, that doesn't involve Newton interpolation polynomial:
$$f(c)=\frac{c-a}{b-a}(f(b)-f(a))+f(a);a=1040,b=1050,c=1044$$

From here, it follows that $f(c)=f(1044)\approx 3.01886957$.

**Question:** How to approximate $f(c)$ by using Newton interpolation polynomial?

Comment: Do you mean Forward or Backward interpolation?

Comment: What do you mean by that (Forward or Backward interpolation)? Is it the first or the second type of a Newton interpolation polynomial?

Comment: Well I dont know what Newton's first type or second type polynomial is. The web also does not seem to. So can you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: If you look on the [Wikipedia page for Newton polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial), you see that you can either use forward divided differences, or backward divided differences. I think forward is more common.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/Numerical%20Analysis/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/rathish-oct31/fratnode6.html